# how to call a typescript method on button click which is present in different .ts file?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular8

I have two .ts files (editor.ts and editor_settings.ts), Corresponding to editor.ts i have creater editor.html file. Now what i am trying to call function inside editor_settings.ts on button click in editor.html.

editor.ts

```
import { EditorSetting } from '../app/editorSetting.component';
export class PadComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy { ---- }
constructor(
    private component: EditorSetting

) { }
    submit() {
    let userCode = this.component.editor.getValue();
    console.log('Inside pad.componet.ts');
    console.log(userCode);
}
```

editor.html

```
<button id="submit" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-run" (click)="submit()" [disabled]="loading" 
        style="background: #FF473A">
         <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <span *ngIf="loading">Running</span>
          <span else> Run </span>
    </button>
```

Now, on button click in editor.html, i want to call function which is inside editor_settings.ts.

editor_settings.ts

```
export class EditorComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, OnChanges {--}
```

I am facing the following error:

```
inline template:0:0 caused by: No provider for EditorComponent!
```

Comment: you mean 2 different components, right? And you want to call method in a sibling component?

Comment: did you add the link to EditorSetting's module to Editor component's module????

Answer (score 2):

To communicate two components that are not related to each other, you can use a service.

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class YourService {

    private yourVariable: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();


    public listenYourVariable() {
        return this.yourVariable.asObservable();

    }


    public yourVariableObserver(value ?: type) {
        this.yourVariable.next(value);
    }
```

You import in yours components where you want use it this service.

```
import{ YourService } from ...
```

In Edit component :

```
submit(){
    this.yourService.yourVariableObserver();
}
```

while in Editor_setting.ts

```
 ngOnInit() {
   this.sub=this.yourService.listenYourVariable().subscribe(
            variable => {
              this.callyourFunction();
            }

        )
    }
```

Don't forget to unsubscribe to prevent memory leak

```
 ngOnDestroy() {
  this.sub.unsubscribe()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another aproach valid if your editor is inside the editorSetting

```
<editor-setting>
   <editor></editor>
</editor-setting>
```

Use Host in constructor

```
constructor(@Optional @Host() private component: EditorSetting) { }
```